# CNAME domain nslookup refused

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record

I have a domain1.ir configured in my dns server as a master zone domain. This is my dns records for this domain:

```
$ttl 1H
domain1.ir.         IN  SOA dns.domain1.ir. info@domain1.ir. (
                2014041610  ; serial
                1D      ; refresh
                1H      ; retry
                1W      ; expire
                1H )        ; minimum

mail.domain1.ir.        IN  CNAME   mail.mailserver.ir.
mail.domain1.ir         IN  CNAME   mail.mailserver.ir
www.domain1.ir.         IN  CNAME   domain1.ir.
www.domain1.com.        IN  CNAME   domain1.ir.
domain1.com.            IN  CNAME   domain1.ir.

domain1.ir.         IN  NS  ns1.dns1.ir.    ; 18
domain1.ir.         IN  NS  dns.dns2.ir.    ; 19
domain1.ir.         IN  NS  dns.dns2.ir.    ; 20
domain1.ir.         IN  NS  ns2.dns1.ir.    ; 21

domain1.ir.         IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
dns.domain1.ir.         IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
dns.domain1.com.        IN  A   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

domain1.ir.         IN  MX  5 mail.domain1.ir.
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.domain1.ir. IN  PTR mail.domain1.ir
domain1.ir.         txt "v=spf1 ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -all"
```

when I try nslookup command like this:

```
nslookup domain1.com localhost
```

I got this error:

```
** server can't find domain1.com: REFUSED
```

What's wrong with my settings?

Comment: Who knows?  It could be many things.  If you're prepared to post the domain name unredacted, we may be able to be more help.

Comment: My domain is vasnews.ir and vasnews.com

Comment: Do I need to create a new zone for my second domain?

Comment: Yes.  Yes, you do, and it needs to be on the nameservers declared as authoritative in the whois, to wit, `dns.mcloud.ir` and `dns.vasnews.ir`.

Comment: what is the type of this zone?

Comment: I'm sorry, what?  As far as I know, a zonefile is a zonefile is a zonefile.  What DNS server implementation are you using on the two nameservers declared authoritative for `vasnews.com`?  Also, you have RRs for `vasnews.com.` in the `vasnews.ir.` zonefile above, and that's not going to work (and may throw errors).

Comment: yes this is a zone file but zone has a type attribute. for master zones I have to set it master but what about this zone? my dns server is named.

Comment: On the master server, it will need to be of type master.  On the slave, it will need to be of type slave.  Of those two DNS servers (see above), you get to pick which is which - and configure them accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no name servers and no authority record configured for `domain1.com` -- how could it possibly work? What would make this server serve that zone?

This could only conceivably work if a nameserver responded to a request by searching every zone in existence to see if any of them contained a matching record. That is, quite obviously, not how name servers work. For one thing, that would mean there would be no possible way to tell who had the right to specify the records inside a zone and no way to reconcile conflicting information from different, unrelated sources.

If `domain1.ir` can contains records for `domain1.com`, why can't `domain2.ir`? How would the nameserver know who has the right to control the DNS for that domain without any SOA or NS records?

Comment: and what is the right records file? would you please write me a sample?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You pasted an example zone filled with the necessary `SOA` and `NS` records.

Comment: You said that there is a problem inside my configuration. Would you please give me a right configuration to set domain1.ir as cname for domain1.com?

Comment: You would have to create a local zone for `ir` that made `domain1.ir` a CNAME for `domain1.com`. But that would cut off access to all other `.ir` domains. Most likely, you are trying to do something that isn't sensible. See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/264913/cant-set-example-com-as-a-cname-record) for more info. Without NS records, how would nameservers know where to go to get the CNAME record? But with a CNAME record, how can you also have a NS records? (Think about what CNAME means.)

Comment: I got it. thank you so much. I just configured my second domain like my first domain and point it to the same ip and handle aliasing or redirecting with apache.